# Rails 4 controller action, Rescue block not working as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, controller

Why doesn't this work?? I expect the rescue block to be executed if an `ActionView::TemplateError` is raised. But that isn't happening for some reason...

The following is a controller action in a rails 4 app.

```
  def categorized
    #ActionView::TemplateError raising code
  rescue ActionView::TemplateError
    binding.pry
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about if move exception in  application_controller.rb:

```
rescue_from ActionView::TemplateError do | exception |
  binding.pry
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
rescue => e
 bindig.pry
```

After you that you can check error class with e.class, to make sure you are catching good exception.

Comment: And I only care about that specific exception

Comment: Of course, you would rescue only from exception you need, but first you make sure that what error you get.

Comment: Like I said, That does not work. And I now know why it doesn't work now. Because the render method is implicitly called after the rescue instruction.